# Replace line in C file, python

Tags: python, regex

I have a C file which contains these lines two lines:

```
(*Something_something_XXXName_1()) = 3.54324E+7;
(*Something_something_XXXName_2()) = 7.13123E+7;
```

When I run my script (will present it later) I want to replace it with new values, for example:

```
(*Something_something_XXXName_1()) = 1.53493E+7;
(*Something_something_XXXName_2()) = 9.12839E+7;
```

Now to my python script

I give an ID

```
ID_File = "anId" #imagine the ID looking like x00...
extracted_id, formated_for_cfile, x = func_name(ID_File)
```

Here I change the value to another one.

```
for c_file in args.cpath:
    f = open(c_file, 'r')
    c_contents = f.read()

    c_replaced_contents = re.sub(r'(.*)Something_something_XXXName_{0}\(\)\) = '.format(x+1) +
                                 '.*;(.*)', r'\Something_something_XXXName_{0}()) = '.format(x+1) +
                                 formated_for_cfile + r';\2', c_contents)
    f.close()

    with open(c_file, 'w') as c_write:
        c_write.write(c_replaced_contents)
```

This function takes the ID and and split it into two values. As you can see it does two stuff as well. From part_str to part_intstr = get normal int values which are converted to string. From str_formated_for_cfile to formated_for_cfile i get the 1.53493E+7 and 9.12839E+7

```
def func_name(ID):
    str_id = ID_File[1:17]
    a_str_id = ''
    for x in range(0, 2):
        part_str = str_id[8 * x:8 * (x + 1)]
        part_int = int(part_str, 16)
        part_intstr = str(part_int)

        str_formated_for_cfile = '{:.7E}'.format(part_int).replace("E+0", "E+")
        formated_for_cfile = re.sub(r'(.*)0+E(.*)', r'\1E\2',str_formated_for_cfile)

        a_str_id = a_str_id.lstrip() + " " + part_intstr
        extracted_id = list(a_str_id.split(' '))

    return extracted_id, formated_for_cfile, x
```

The issue is that is not replacing the line on my C file. What am i missing?

Here is the script where the code is next to each other (just for simpler readability):

```
ID_File = "anId" #imagine the ID looking like x00...
extracted_id, formated_for_cfile, x = func_name(ID_File)

for c_file in args.cpath:
    f = open(c_file, 'r')
    c_contents = f.read()

    c_replaced_contents = re.sub(r'(.*)Something_something_XXXName_{0}\(\)\) = '.format(x+1) +
                                 '.*;(.*)', r'\Something_something_XXXName_{0}()) = '.format(x+1) +
                                 formated_for_cfile + r';\2', c_contents)
    f.close()

    with open(c_file, 'w') as c_write:
        c_write.write(c_replaced_contents)

def func_name(ID):
    str_id = ID_File[1:17]
    a_str_id = ''
    for x in range(0, 2):
        part_str = str_id[8 * x:8 * (x + 1)]
        part_int = int(part_str, 16)
        part_intstr = str(part_int)

        str_formated_for_cfile = '{:.7E}'.format(part_int).replace("E+0", "E+")
        formated_for_cfile = re.sub(r'(.*)0+E(.*)', r'\1E\2',str_formated_for_cfile)

        a_str_id = a_str_id.lstrip() + " " + part_intstr
        extracted_id = list(a_str_id.split(' '))

    return extracted_id, formated_for_cfile, x
```

Comment: Why don't you try [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)?

Comment: what is the value in "c_replaced_contents" when you run the script? is it correct?

Comment: @Vivek Nope, it is still the old values.

Comment: It's probable that your regular expression pattern is slightly incorrect. But the way you write your code makes it hard to debug. You do way too many things in the same line as `re.sub`. Create the pattern and replacement string first and print it out. What are the actual arguments?

Answer (score 0):

**Using sed**

```
sed s/'(*Something_something_XXXName_1())'/'(*Something_something_XXXName_1())=1.53493E+7;\/\/'/g file.c >new_file.c
```

OR

```
#define NEW_VAL 1.53493E+7
sed s/'(*Something_something_XXXName_1())'/'(*Something_something_XXXName_1())=NEW_VALUE;\/\/'/g file.c >new_file.c
```

Comment: I will suggest the second way using MACRO so that you can easily change in future.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your regular expression.
In the first argument you have `Something_something_XXXName_{0}`, but this will not match `Something_something_XXXName_1`. Instead it should be something like `Something_something_XXXName_\d` or `Something_something_XXXName_(\d+)`. In the second argument, `\S` means match any non-white-space character, you probably meant `\1S`.

Comment: Well i need the {0} beccause I do x+1 which gives me 1 and 2 since the range in the for loop is (0,2). And regarding second argument it shoud be \1S, just forgot to add it there when I posted here.

Comment: Well when i add \d+ I get the sort of correct output. Instead of writing Something_something_XXXName_1 it writes Something_something_XXXName_16